# Why NaNs when creating a dataframe with pd.Dataframe() and setting the index manually?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's consider this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4), columns = ['A', 'B', 'AB', 'O'])
df

Out[1]:
        A           B          AB           O
0   0.704744    0.032988    0.514788    0.405281
1   0.978119    0.354312    0.273255    0.908691
2   0.653161    0.337653    0.309225    0.008059
3   0.023022    0.110995    0.751048    0.088853
```

Now let's say we want to select two columns, and use another column as an index. We can use `set_index()` and get it done easily, but let's try a more cumbersome approach, and use `pd.DataFrame()`:

```
pd.DataFrame(df[['B','AB']], index = df['A'].values)

Out[2]:
             B  AB
0.704744    NaN NaN
0.978119    NaN NaN
0.653161    NaN NaN
0.023022    NaN NaN
```

Why this resulted in `NaN` values?

The same problem arises if I pass a list of integers as index (example `index = [10,11,12,13]`).

We can fix this problem quite easily by passing the data as a `numpy.ndarray` with `df[['B','AB']].values`. No `NaN` values will be displayed this way.

Also, no `NaN` values are displayed with `pd.DataFrame(df[['B','AB']])` where the index is not specified anymore.

But, again, why the `NaN` values for the code above?

Comment: Because there are no values for `B` and `AB` at index `10`, `11`, `0.704744`, etc.

Comment: Interesting. You mean the values I pass to the `index` parameter are used to select datapoints in `df[['B', 'AB']]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you pass a dataframe as the first parameter of the `DataFrame` constructor, it will construct a new dataframe with the given index, and **assign values from the original dataframe given there are values for that index**.

For instance if you write:

```
pd.DataFrame(df[['B','AB']],index=[0,2])
```

It will select the first and third row:

```
          A         B        AB         O
0  0.501622  0.422913  0.570804  0.507912
1  0.507934  0.698122  0.745761  0.201501
2  0.333501  0.567291  0.472924  0.813184
3  0.788795  0.733176  0.843651  0.603158
>>> pd.DataFrame(df[['B','AB']],index=[0,2])
          B        AB
0  0.422913  0.570804
2  0.567291  0.472924
```

Since there are no values for floating points (like in your question `0.704744`), it will fill the missing values with `NaN`s.

You can however easily obtain what you want by writing:

```
>>> df[['A', 'B', 'AB']].set_index('A')
                 B        AB
A                           
0.501622  0.422913  0.570804
0.507934  0.698122  0.745761
0.333501  0.567291  0.472924
0.788795  0.733176  0.843651
```